# Add contacts to group using CSV with contact e-mails

Tags: import, tags

I'm looking for a way to add contacts to a group from a CSV file including e-mails of contacts already existing in Civi.

When I import into Civi, I use the **update option** and select **primary e-mail**, and even when the e-mail is the same, it ads a second e-mail entry with the same e-mail that already exists.

Is there a way around this? It doesn't seem like it's the correct action as it pollutes the contact card with repeated e-mail entries.

Comment: It may be worth you confirming this problem replicates on Demo

Answer (score 2):

You have to select an appropiate Dedupe Rule so that the importer can detect by which criteria you want to treat an existing contact and a imported contact as the same.

Using the predefined Email - Unsupervised Rule should work for this purpose.

[image]

If you chose the same location as is defined for the contact email it will just update the existing contact.

However, the option to select the primary e-mail does not seem to be working as expected. It will create a new adress without setting a proper location.

[image]

You may want to report this as a bug.

Comment: This is the exact setup I did for the dedupe rule. The issue that I'm having is like the screenshot you added, where if the contact's e-mail is "work" and for whatever reason I'm importing all as "main" and set as primary, I then get a duplicate e-mail in the record for which the primary e-mail isn't set to "main".